# What factors accounted for the pattern of caranvanserai across Eurasia?

Tags: europe, economy, trade, asia

This is a question we had in an AP World History test last week:

[image]

I was able to answer (c) correctly (improvements in sea navigation and technology caused more and more people to transition from land-trading to sea-trading), but I had no idea how to answer questions (a) and (b).

I haven't been able to find this question online, and I just don't know what accounts for the pattern of the caravanserai (it seems that Persia and the Middle East has a much higher density of caravanserai, essentially the "pattern", but I don't know what to use to explain that). In the test, the answers I put were that the increase in trade and the use of caravans resulted in the increase in the number of caravanserai (doesn't really describe the "pattern" of them though).

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would have thought it’d be a) geographical and b) human need for trade, which gave rise to the “silk roads”. If you join the dots, then look at a map of silk roads, I assume this is the “pattern” reference in the question. Middle East has “more” caravanserais because their materials were mainly stone (for archaeologists to discover later). Presumably eastern cultures used less durable materials further east (Central/Inner Asia) and geography again (steppe and desert).

Comment: I've got several things I'm noticing, but also I'd think the text for this course would answer this question, wouldn't it?

Comment: I just tried looking through the AP handbook for this course and after a lot of scrolling I found this question in it, but I think the answer they give is very vague. Here's another link that I found that uses the answer they give in the AP handbook: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:VAtO2w8727QJ:https://mrbanksapworldhistory.weebly.com/uploads/5/1/9/9/51992211/sample_free_response.pdf+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

The question is at the bottom of the first page.

Comment: Additionally, here's another answer that I just found, and I can't understand this one either: https://quizlet.com/249918368/ap-world-short-answer-flash-cards/

The question is on the first flashcard.

Comment: Please edit the newly-found information in the body of the question and explain what exactly doesn't make sense for you?